# Proving $\Bbb R^n$ can be covered with a countable number of special sets.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

**Previous results.** We define a Sterntaler $S$ to be a bounded set of $\Bbb R^n$ in which $0 \in S$ and $rx \in S, \forall x \in S \text{ and } r \in [0,1]$. Also we define, for any open Sterntaler $S$, the sets $S_\epsilon(x) = \{x + \epsilon y : y \in S\}, x \in \Bbb R^n, \epsilon > 0$. In a previous exercise, we have shown that the sets $S_\epsilon(x)$ defined before form a basis for the Euclidian Topology on $\Bbb R^n$.

**Exercise.** Show that we can cover the space $\Bbb R^n$ with a countable number of $S_\epsilon(x)$ with $\epsilon$ fixed.

**My attempt.** Observe that $\mathcal{B} = \{B_r(q) : q \in \Bbb Q^n, r \in \Bbb Q\}$ is a countable basis of $\Bbb R^n$, under the Euclidian topology. (It is a basis since $\overline{\Bbb Q^n} = \Bbb R^n$ and it is countable since $\Bbb Q^n$ is countable), i.e., $\Bbb Q^n$ covers $\Bbb R^n$. From previous results, we have shown that $S_\epsilon(x)$ is a basis under the Euclidian topology on $\Bbb R^n$ and thus it is also a base for $\mathcal{B}$ (it is a subset of $\Bbb R^n$), i.e., $S_\epsilon(x)$ covers all of $\mathcal{B}$ e thus it covers all of $\Bbb R^n$. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is countable, we only need a countable number of $S_\epsilon(x)$ to cover all of $\Bbb R^n$.

Basically I was just wondering if my approach is correct, and if not, looking for the correct one. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Be careful with sets of points vs sets of sets. $\mathcal{B}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @FlorianR How does that invalidate my attempt? Thanks for the help

Comment: $\Bbb Q^n$ does not cover $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is too vague. Let us show that the countably many sets $S_\epsilon(q)$ with $q \in \mathbb Q^n$ cover $\mathbb R^n$.

Since $S$ is open and $0 \in S$, there exists $r > 0$ such that $B_r(0) \subset S$.

Consider $x \in \mathbb R^n$. Since $\mathbb Q^n$ is dense in $\mathbb R^n$, we find $q  \in \mathbb Q^n$ such that $\lVert x - q \rVert < \epsilon r$.  Then $y = \frac{1}{\epsilon}(x - q)$ has the property $\lVert y \rVert < r$ and thus $y \in S$. This shows that
$$x = q + \epsilon y \in S_\epsilon(q) .$$

Comment: So it was this simple... Thanks for the help! It made sense to me

Comment: $||x-q||$ stands for $d(x,q)$ in $\Bbb R^n$ right?

Comment: @Seabourn Yes, it is the Euclidean distance = Euclidean norm of the difference.